# autocomplete named directories

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

Autocompletion of a named directory doesn't seem to work before I use it the first time, as demonstrated by the following session:

```
% setfoo() { foo=/etc; }
% setfoo

% cd ~fo<Tab> # doesn't autocomplete ~foo
% ls ~foo # this works
% cd ~fo<Tab> # now it does autocomplete ~foo
```

Is there a way to enable autocompletion from the beginning?

Notes:

- this works as expected if I set `foo` directly on the command line, not inside a function
- `setfoo() { foo=/etc; true ~foo; }` works, too, but I'm looking for a more proper solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `hash -d` to define named directories explicitly:

```
hash -d foo=/etc
```

Note: this does not set the corresponding parameter:

```
% hash -d foo=/etc
% echo $foo

% echo ~foo
/etc
```

`hash -d` without any arguments will print the named directiories hash table.